# Receive range of dates. If starting dating doesn't exist fetch range from the closest past date

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a MySQL query that gets me historical price changes of a product to display later on a chart - based on range of dates.

For example:

```
Select * from HistoryPrices 
where StartDate>='1-1-2016' and EndDate<='1-20-2016' 
where ProductID=505
```

This is fine. This is where it becomes more interesting.
If `1-1-2016` doesn't contain any product price change, I will need to fetch the past closest date of `1-1-2016` and fill it out for `1-1-2016` in the results.

Lets say `12-25-2015` is the closest past date of price change.

Example:

table looks like:

```
Date        Price
12-25-2015  44.5
1-3-2016    50.5
1-4-2016    45.6
1-10-2016   40.99
1-15-2016   50.50
1-22-2016   50.99
```

MySQL query result should look like (from 1-1-2016 to 1-20-2016):

```
1-1-2016    44.5
1-3-2016    50.5
1-4-2016    45.6
1-10-2016   40.99
1-15-2016   50.50
```

Notice price of `1-1-2016` got `12-15-2015` price.

Looking for an MySQL query that can achieve this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your sample date:

```
select *
from HistoryPrices
where `Date` >= date('2016-01-01') and `Date` <= date('2016-01-20')
union (
    select '2016-01-01', Price
    from HistoryPrices
    where `Date` <= date('2016-01-01')
    order by `date` desc
    limit 1
)
order by `date`
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcf944/3)

[<kbd>And Demo with 2016-01-01 included in data</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f68/4)

Comment: There is a problem with this query. look at the sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcf944/9  it should return only one result (last one) and not two results.

Comment: @Dror So if the day of min date is not `01`, you will do not need this day's `Price`?

Comment: my mistake, in the url sample i gave you it works.. i don't know why but in my environment i get another previous price with starting date. not sure why. strange. query is the same.

Comment: @Dror Notice your column's type. `date` is different from `datetime`.