# How do mysql order by when column's alias and column's name are the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

Related this [Receive range of dates. If starting dating doesn't exist fetch range from the closest past date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588527/receive-range-of-dates-if-starting-dating-doesnt-exist-fetch-range-from-the-cl), I have encountered a weird issue.

Here table `HistoryPrices` like this:

```
|    Date    | Price |
|------------|-------|
| 2015-12-25 |  44.5 |
| 2016-01-01 |  90.5 |
| 2016-01-03 |  50.5 |
| 2016-01-04 |  45.6 |
| 2016-01-10 | 40.99 |
| 2016-01-15 |  50.5 |
| 2016-01-22 | 50.99 |
```

When I ran this query:

```
select *
from HistoryPrices
order by `date` desc
limit 1;
```

I got the right row [`| 2016-01-22 | 50.99 |`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f68/8).

When I ran this:

```
select '2016-01-22', Price
from HistoryPrices
order by `date` desc
limit 1;
```

Also the right expected result [`| 2016-01-22 | 50.99 |`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f68/10)

And this query:

```
select '2016-01-22' as xxx, Price
from HistoryPrices
order by `date` desc
limit 1;
```

Also [`| 2016-01-22 | 50.99 |`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f68/11)

However, when I ran this:

```
select '2016-01-22' as `date`, Price
from HistoryPrices
order by `date` desc
limit 1;
```

I got this result [`| 2016-01-22 | 44.5 |`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f68/9). I have no idea why this happened. Maybe the column alias and the column name are the same `date`, then when `` order by `date` ``, mysql don't know how to do that? But I can not confirm this.

Can anyone do some explanation to me please?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL allows column aliases to be referenced in the `order by`.  If you want the table name, then qualify the column:

```
select '2016-01-22' as `date`, hp.Price
from HistoryPrices hp
order by hp.`date` desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for so fast answer, also I know what you said here, but as you saw, the last query gave me 44.5, how did this happen?

Comment: @JPG . . . It is using the column defined in the `select`.  All the rows have the same value, so an indeterminate row is chosen.